# Where to obtain a list of active NDB approaches?

Tags: usa, iaps, approach

Does anyone know where to find a list of active NDB approaches? I can find a list of ones proposed to be eliminated, but I'm having a problem coming across a list of remaining ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This list comes from a database query against an ARINC 424 navigation database. The data is [available on a subscription basis (for a fee) from the FAA](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/productcatalog/digitalproducts/nfd/) as a raw, computer-readable data file, but it is not human readable, and querying it requires special software not accessible to the typical interested party. I have done the query for you and pasted the results.

Note the database doesn't distinguish between "NDB RWY XX" and "NDB OR GPS RWY XX" so the titles here may not precisely match what you see on the plate.

Time permitting I'll see if I can update the list (and note any changes) using the most up-to-date navigation database. This list is based on an expired (by 2 months or so) database. These approaches are dropping like flies.

```
02A  NDB RWY 26  (CLANTON, AL)
06FA NDB RWY 09  (JUPITER, FL)
06FA NDB RWY 27  (JUPITER, FL)
0F2  NDB RWY 17  (BOWIE, TX)
0F2  NDB RWY 35  (BOWIE, TX)
0M3  NDB RWY 02  (HOHENWALD, TN)
15F  NDB RWY 18  (HASKELL, TX)
16G  NDB RWY 24  (TIFFIN, OH)
1B1  NDB-A       (HUDSON, NY)
1B9  NDB RWY 32  (MANSFIELD, MA)
1G3  NDB RWY 01  (KENT, OH)
1H8  NDB RWY 04  (CASEY, IL)
1H8  NDB RWY 22  (CASEY, IL)
1J0  NDB-A       (BONIFAY, FL)
1S3  NDB RWY 26  (FORSYTH, MT)
21D  NDB RWY 04  (ST PAUL, MN)
23R  NDB RWY 35  (DEVINE, TX)
28J  NDB RWY 09  (PALATKA, FL)
2A0  NDB RWY 03  (DAYTON, TN)
2B7  NDB RWY 36  (PITTSFIELD, ME)
2F5  NDB RWY 16  (LAMESA, TX)
2F5  NDB RWY 34  (LAMESA, TX)
2G9  NDB RWY 25  (SOMERSET, PA)
2H0  NDB-A       (SHELBYVILLE, IL)
2J5  NDB RWY 17  (MILLEN, GA)
2M2  NDB RWY 17  (LAWRENCEBURG, TN)
2R6  NDB RWY 36  (BUNKIE, LA)
35A  NDB RWY 05  (UNION, SC)
3B4  NDB-B       (ELIOT, ME)
3F3  NDB RWY 18  (MANSFIELD, LA)
3F4  NDB RWY 09  (VIVIAN, LA)
3JC  NDB-B       (JUNCTION CITY, KS)
45R  NDB RWY 13  (KOUNTZE/SILSBEE, TX)
48Y  NDB RWY 33  (PINECREEK, MN)
4A9  NDB-A       (FT PAYNE, AL)
4F2  NDB RWY 35  (CARTHAGE, TX)
4K6  NDB RWY 36  (BLOOMFIELD, IA)
4R7  NDB RWY 16  (EUNICE, LA)
4V8  NDB RWY 01  (WEST DOVER, VT)
53A  NDB RWY 18  (MONTEZUMA, GA)
5R4  NDB RWY 18  (FOLEY, AL)
5R8  NDB RWY 16  (DE QUINCY, LA)
6B6  NDB-A       (STOW, MA)
70J  NDB RWY 13  (CAIRO, GA)
79J  NDB RWY 29  (ANDALUSIA/OPP, AL)
79J  NDB-A       (ANDALUSIA/OPP, AL)
7F3  NDB RWY 35  (CADDO MILLS, TX)
8A0  NDB-A       (ALBERTVILLE, AL)
8B0  NDB-A       (RANGELEY, ME)
8F3  NDB RWY 35  (CROSBYTON, TX)
8G2  NDB RWY 14  (CORRY, PA)
D73  NDB-A       (MONROE, GA)
E30  NDB RWY 35  (BALLINGER, TX)
E38  NDB RWY 19  (ALPINE, TX)
F10  NDB RWY 36  (HENRYETTA, OK)
F17  NDB RWY 17  (CENTER, TX)
F44  NDB RWY 35  (ATHENS, TX)
F46  NDB-A       (ROCKWALL, TX)
F99  NDB RWY 17  (HOLDENVILLE, OK)
I23  NDB RWY 23  (WASHINGTON COURT HOUSE, OH)
I68  NDB-A       (LEBANON, OH)
I69  NDB RWY 22  (BATAVIA, OH)
K34  NDB-D       (GARDNER, KS)
K88  NDB RWY 01  (IOLA, KS)
KAAA NDB RWY 21  (LINCOLN, IL)
KAAF NDB RWY 14  (APALACHICOLA, FL)
KAAF NDB RWY 32  (APALACHICOLA, FL)
KAAS NDB RWY 23  (CAMPBELLSVILLE, KY)
KABI NDB RWY 35R (ABILENE, TX)
KABR NDB RWY 31  (ABERDEEN, SD)
KABY NDB RWY 04  (ALBANY, GA)
KACK NDB RWY 24  (NANTUCKET, MA)
KACP NDB RWY 36  (OAKDALE, LA)
KADF NDB RWY 04  (ARKADELPHIA, AR)
KADG NDB RWY 05  (ADRIAN, MI)
KAFK NDB RWY 15  (NEBRASKA CITY, NE)
KAFK NDB RWY 33  (NEBRASKA CITY, NE)
KAHN NDB RWY 27  (ATHENS, GA)
KAHQ NDB RWY 20  (WAHOO, NE)
KAID NDB RWY 30  (ANDERSON, IN)
KAIK NDB RWY 25  (AIKEN, SC)
KAIT NDB RWY 16  (AITKIN, MN)
KAJR NDB RWY 06  (CORNELIA, GA)
KAKH NDB RWY 03  (GASTONIA, NC)
KAKQ NDB RWY 20  (WAKEFIELD, VA)
KAKR NDB RWY 25  (AKRON, OH)
KALN NDB RWY 17  (ALTON-ST LOUIS, IL)
KALW NDB RWY 20  (WALLA WALLA, WA)
KALX NDB-A       (ALEXANDER CITY, AL)
KAMA NDB RWY 04  (AMARILLO, TX)
KAMT NDB RWY 23  (WEST UNION, OH)
KANB NDB RWY 05  (ANNISTON, AL)
KANQ NDB RWY 05  (ANGOLA, IN)
KAPG NDB RWY 22  (ABERDEEN PROVING GROUNDS, MD)
KAPN NDB RWY 01  (ALPENA, MI)
KAPT NDB RWY 04  (JASPER, TN)
KAQP NDB RWY 13  (APPLETON, MN)
KARM NDB RWY 14  (WHARTON, TX)
KARM NDB RWY 32  (WHARTON, TX)
KARV NDB RWY 28  (MINOCQUA-WOODRUFF, WI)
KASH NDB RWY 14  (NASHUA, NH)
KATA NDB RWY 05  (ATLANTA, TX)
KATS NDB RWY 12  (ARTESIA, NM)
KATS NDB RWY 30  (ARTESIA, NM)
KATY NDB RWY 35  (WATERTOWN, SD)
KAVQ NDB RWY 12  (MARANA, AZ)
KAWG NDB RWY 31  (WASHINGTON, IA)
KAWO NDB RWY 34  (ARLINGTON, WA)
KAXA NDB RWY 12  (ALGONA, IA)
KAZC NDB-A       (COLORADO CITY, AZ)
KAZE NDB RWY 14  (HAZLEHURST, GA)
KAZO NDB RWY 35  (KALAMAZOO, MI)
KBBB NDB RWY 14  (BENSON, MN)
KBBD NDB RWY 17  (BRADY, TX)
KBBP NDB RWY 07  (BENNETTSVILLE, SC)
KBCB NDB-A       (BLACKSBURG, VA)
KBED NDB RWY 29  (BEDFORD, MA)
KBEH NDB RWY 28  (BENTON HARBOR, MI)
KBFK NDB-A       (BUFFALO, OK)
KBFW NDB RWY 25  (SILVER BAY, MN)
KBGF NDB RWY 18  (WINCHESTER, TN)
KBHC NDB RWY 08  (BAXLEY, GA)
KBHK NDB RWY 13  (BAKER, MT)
KBHK NDB RWY 31  (BAKER, MT)
KBIL NDB RWY 10L (BILLINGS, MT)
KBKS NDB RWY 35  (FALFURRIAS, TX)
KBKT NDB-A       (BLACKSTONE, VA)
KBMC NDB-A       (BRIGHAM CITY, UT)
KBOI NDB RWY 10R (BOISE, ID)
KBPP NDB RWY 29  (BOWMAN, ND)
KBQP NDB RWY 34  (BASTROP, LA)
KBRD NDB RWY 23  (BRAINERD, MN)
KBST NDB RWY 15  (BELFAST, ME)
KBTL NDB RWY 23R (BATTLE CREEK, MI)
KBTR NDB RWY 31  (BATON ROUGE, LA)
KBUB NDB RWY 15  (BURWELL, NE)
KBVS NDB RWY 11  (BURLINGTON/MT VERNON, WA)
KBWG NDB RWY 03  (BOWLING GREEN, KY)
KCAV NDB RWY 14  (CLARION, IA)
KCBG NDB RWY 34  (CAMBRIDGE, MN)
KCBK NDB RWY 17  (COLBY, KS)
KCCY NDB RWY 12  (CHARLES CITY, IA)
KCDA NDB RWY 02  (LYNDONVILLE, VT)
KCDR NDB RWY 20  (CHADRON, NE)
KCEU NDB RWY 25  (CLEMSON, SC)
KCFJ NDB RWY 04  (CRAWFORDSVILLE, IN)
KCFV NDB RWY 35  (COFFEYVILLE, KS)
KCGE NDB RWY 34  (CAMBRIDGE, MD)
KCHD NDB RWY 04R (CHANDLER, AZ)
KCHQ NDB RWY 36  (CHARLESTON, MO)
KCII NDB RWY 23  (CHOTEAU, MT)
KCIR NDB RWY 14  (CAIRO, IL)
KCIU NDB RWY 34  (SAULT STE MARIE, MI)
KCJR NDB RWY 04  (CULPEPER, VA)
KCKC NDB RWY 27  (GRAND MARAIS, MN)
KCKF NDB RWY 10  (CORDELE, GA)
KCKI NDB RWY 14  (KINGSTREE, SC)
KCKN NDB RWY 13  (CROOKSTON, MN)
KCMI NDB RWY 32R (CHAMPAIGN-URBANA, IL)
KCMY NDB RWY 29  (SPARTA, WI)
KCNH NDB-A       (CLAREMONT, NH)
KCNI NDB RWY 05  (CANTON, GA)
KCNK NDB-A       (CONCORDIA, KS)
KCNP NDB RWY 30  (CHAPPELL, NE)
KCNW NDB RWY 35R (WACO, TX)
KCOE NDB RWY 06  (COEUR D'ALENE, ID)
KCOQ NDB RWY 17  (CLOQUET, MN)
KCOQ NDB RWY 35  (CLOQUET, MN)
KCOS NDB RWY 35L (COLORADO SPRINGS, CO)
KCPC NDB RWY 06  (WHITEVILLE, NC)
KCQB NDB RWY 35  (CHANDLER, OK)
KCQX NDB-A       (CHATHAM, MA)
KCRS NDB RWY 14  (CORSICANA, TX)
KCRS NDB RWY 32  (CORSICANA, TX)
KCSB NDB RWY 14  (CAMBRIDGE, NE)
KCSB NDB RWY 32  (CAMBRIDGE, NE)
KCSQ NDB RWY 34  (CRESTON, IA)
KCUH NDB RWY 36  (CUSHING, OK)
KCVC NDB RWY 28  (ATLANTA, GA)
KCVO NDB RWY 17  (CORVALLIS, OR)
KCVX NDB RWY 09  (CHARLEVOIX, MI)
KCVX NDB RWY 27  (CHARLEVOIX, MI)
KCWC NDB RWY 35  (WICHITA FALLS, TX)
KCWS NDB-A       (CONWAY, AR)
KCWV NDB RWY 09  (CLAXTON, GA)
KCXO NDB RWY 14  (HOUSTON, TX)
KCXU NDB RWY 08  (CAMILLA, GA)
KCYS NDB RWY 27  (CHEYENNE, WY)
KCYW NDB RWY 35  (CLAY CENTER, KS)
KCZT NDB RWY 31  (CARRIZO SPRINGS, TX)
KDAA NDB RWY 32  (FT BELVOIR, VA)
KDAW NDB RWY 33  (ROCHESTER, NH)
KDAW NDB-B       (ROCHESTER, NH)
KDAY NDB RWY 06R (DAYTON, OH)
KDCM NDB RWY 35  (CHESTER, SC)
KDET NDB RWY 15  (DETROIT, MI)
KDEW NDB-A       (DEER PARK, WA)
KDLC NDB RWY 07  (DILLON, SC)
KDLZ NDB RWY 10  (DELAWARE, OH)
KDMO NDB RWY 18  (SEDALIA, MO)
KDMO NDB RWY 36  (SEDALIA, MO)
KDNL NDB RWY 11  (AUGUSTA, GA)
KDNL NDB RWY DMC (AUGUSTA, GA)
KDNS NDB RWY 30  (DENISON, IA)
KDRI NDB RWY 36  (DE RIDDER, LA)
KDRT NDB RWY 13  (DEL RIO, TX)
KDTO NDB RWY 18  (DENTON, TX)
KDVK NDB-A       (DANVILLE, KY)
KDXX NDB RWY 32  (MADISON, MN)
KDYB NDB RWY 06  (SUMMERVILLE, SC)
KEAR NDB RWY 36  (KEARNEY, NE)
KEAU NDB RWY 22  (EAU CLAIRE, WI)
KEBS NDB RWY 32  (WEBSTER CITY, IA)
KECG NDB RWY 10  (ELIZABETH CITY, NC)
KEFW NDB RWY 32  (JEFFERSON, IA)
KEGQ NDB RWY 13  (EMMETSBURG, IA)
KEGQ NDB RWY 31  (EMMETSBURG, IA)
KEGT NDB RWY 35  (WELLINGTON, KS)
KEHA NDB RWY 35  (ELKHART, KS)
KEHO NDB RWY 23  (SHELBY, NC)
KEMT NDB-C       (EL MONTE, CA)
KEOE NDB RWY 22  (NEWBERRY, SC)
KEOK NDB RWY 14  (KEOKUK, IA)
KEOK NDB RWY 26  (KEOKUK, IA)
KEOP NDB RWY 25  (WAVERLY, OH)
KEPM NDB RWY 15  (EASTPORT, ME)
KEPM NDB RWY 33  (EASTPORT, ME)
KERI NDB RWY 06  (ERIE, PA)
KERI NDB RWY 24  (ERIE, PA)
KERV NDB RWY 30  (KERRVILLE, TX)
KETC NDB RWY 27  (TARBORO, NC)
KETN NDB RWY 35  (EASTLAND, TX)
KEUL NDB RWY 30  (CALDWELL, ID)
KEVB NDB RWY 29  (NEW SMYRNA BEACH, FL)
KEVV NDB RWY 22  (EVANSVILLE, IN)
KEVY NDB-A       (MIDDLETOWN, DE)
KEWB NDB RWY 05  (NEW BEDFORD, MA)
KEWK NDB RWY 35  (NEWTON, KS)
KEYE NDB RWY 21  (INDIANAPOLIS, IN)
KEYW NDB-A       (KEY WEST, FL)
KEZF NDB RWY 24  (FREDERICKSBURG, VA)
KEZM NDB RWY 02  (EASTMAN, GA)
KEZZ NDB RWY 35  (CAMERON, MO)
KFAF NDB RWY 14  (FT EUSTIS, VA)
KFBG NDB RWY 27  (FT BRAGG, NC)
KFBY NDB-A       (FAIRBURY, NE)
KFCH NDB-B       (FRESNO, CA)
KFDW NDB RWY 04  (WINNSBORO, SC)
KFES NDB RWY 36  (FESTUS, MO)
KFFC NDB RWY 31  (ATLANTA, GA)
KFFL NDB RWY 36  (FAIRFIELD, IA)
KFFM NDB RWY 31  (FERGUS FALLS, MN)
KFHR NDB RWY 34  (FRIDAY HARBOR, WA)
KFHU NDB RWY 26  (FT HUACHUCA, AZ)
KFIT NDB RWY 20  (FITCHBURG, MA)
KFIT NDB-A       (FITCHBURG, MA)
KFKR NDB RWY 09  (FRANKFORT, IN)
KFLV NDB RWY 34  (FT LEAVENWORTH, KS)
KFMH NDB RWY 23  (FALMOUTH, MA)
KFMZ NDB RWY 17  (FAIRMONT, NE)
KFMZ NDB RWY 35  (FAIRMONT, NE)
KFNB NDB-A       (FALLS CITY, NE)
KFOE NDB RWY 13  (TOPEKA, KS)
KFOZ NDB RWY 15  (BIGFORK, MN)
KFPR NDB RWY 28L (FT PIERCE, FL)
KFPR NDB-A       (FT PIERCE, FL)
KFRG NDB RWY 01  (FARMINGDALE, NY)
KFRI NDB RWY 04  (FT RILEY, KS)
KFSE NDB RWY 34  (FOSSTON, MN)
KFSI NDB RWY 17  (FT SILL, OK)
KFSI NDB-A       (FT SILL, OK)
KFSK NDB RWY 18  (FT SCOTT, KS)
KFSM NDB RWY 25  (FT SMITH, AR)
KFTG NDB RWY 26  (DENVER, CO)
KFTK NDB RWY 18  (FT KNOX, KY)
KFTY NDB RWY 08  (ATLANTA, GA)
KFVX NDB RWY 03  (FARMVILLE, VA)
KFWC NDB RWY 09  (FAIRFIELD, IL)
KFXY NDB RWY 33  (FOREST CITY, IA)
KFYE NDB RWY 19  (SOMERVILLE, TN)
KFYM NDB RWY 20  (FAYETTEVILLE, TN)
KFZG NDB RWY 01  (FITZGERALD, GA)
KFZI NDB RWY 27  (FOSTORIA, OH)
KGAI NDB RWY 14  (GAITHERSBURG, MD)
KGBD NDB RWY 35  (GREAT BEND, KS)
KGBR NDB-A       (GREAT BARRINGTON, MA)
KGCK NDB RWY 35  (GARDEN CITY, KS)
KGCY NDB RWY 05  (GREENEVILLE, TN)
KGDV NDB RWY 12  (GLENDIVE, MT)
KGEY NDB RWY 34  (GREYBULL, WY)
KGGE NDB RWY 05  (GEORGETOWN, SC)
KGGF NDB RWY 15  (GRANT, NE)
KGGF NDB RWY 33  (GRANT, NE)
KGGG NDB RWY 13  (LONGVIEW, TX)
KGGW NDB RWY 30  (GLASGOW, MT)
KGHG NDB RWY 06  (MARSHFIELD, MA)
KGHG NDB RWY 24  (MARSHFIELD, MA)
KGLR NDB RWY 09  (GAYLORD, MI)
KGLY NDB RWY 04  (CLINTON, MO)
KGLY NDB RWY 22  (CLINTON, MO)
KGMU NDB RWY 01  (GREENVILLE, SC)
KGNC NDB RWY 35  (SEMINOLE, TX)
KGNF NDB RWY 13  (GRENADA, MS)
KGNG NDB RWY 25  (GOODING, ID)
KGOV NDB RWY 14  (GRAYLING, MI)
KGRD NDB RWY 27  (GREENWOOD, SC)
KGRF NDB RWY 15  (FT LEWIS, WA)
KGRF NDB RWY 33  (FT LEWIS, WA)
KGRK NDB RWY 15  (FT HOOD, TX)
KGRN NDB RWY 22  (GORDON, NE)
KGSO NDB RWY 14  (GREENSBORO, NC)
KGTB NDB RWY 15  (FT DRUM, NY)
KGTB NDB RWY 33  (FT DRUM, NY)
KGTF NDB RWY 34  (GREAT FALLS, MT)
KGUR NDB RWY 32  (GUERNSEY, WY)
KGUY NDB RWY 18  (GUYMON, OK)
KGVL NDB RWY 05  (GAINESVILLE, GA)
KGWR NDB RWY 34  (GWINNER, ND)
KGXY NDB RWY 34  (GREELEY, CO)
KGYH NDB RWY 05  (GREENVILLE, SC)
KGYI NDB RWY 17L (SHERMAN-DENISON, TX)
KGYL NDB RWY 31  (GLENCOE, MN)
KGYY NDB RWY 30  (GARY, IN)
KHBV NDB RWY 13  (HEBBRONVILLE, TX)
KHDO NDB RWY 35R (HONDO, TX)
KHEG NDB-A       (JACKSONVILLE, FL)
KHFF NDB RWY 11  (CAMP MACKALL, NC)
KHFY NDB RWY 01  (INDIANAPOLIS, IN)
KHHG NDB RWY 09  (HUNTINGTON, IN)
KHHW NDB RWY 35  (HUGO, OK)
KHIO NDB-B       (PORTLAND, OR)
KHJH NDB RWY 12  (HEBRON, NE)
KHLN NDB-D       (HELENA, MT)
KHMY NDB RWY 17  (LEXINGTON, OK)
KHMY NDB RWY 35  (LEXINGTON, OK)
KHNZ NDB RWY 06  (OXFORD-HENDERSON, NC)
KHOC NDB RWY 23  (HILLSBORO, OH)
KHOE NDB RWY 14  (HOMERVILLE, GA)
KHOP NDB RWY 23  (FT CAMPBELL/HOPKINSVILLE, KY)
KHQG NDB RWY 02  (HUGOTON, KS)
KHQU NDB RWY 10  (THOMSON, GA)
KHRJ NDB RWY 23  (ERWIN, NC)
KHRO NDB RWY 18  (HARRISON, AR)
KHRU NDB RWY 17  (HERINGTON, KS)
KHRU NDB RWY 35  (HERINGTON, KS)
KHRX NDB RWY 20  (HEREFORD, TX)
KHSA NDB RWY 18  (BAY ST LOUIS, MS)
KHUA NDB RWY 17  (REDSTONE ARSENAL, AL)
KHUT NDB RWY 13  (HUTCHINSON, KS)
KHVC NDB RWY 26  (HOPKINSVILLE, KY)
KHVS NDB RWY 03  (HARTSVILLE, SC)
KHVS NDB RWY 21  (HARTSVILLE, SC)
KHYI NDB RWY 13  (SAN MARCOS, TX)
KHYW NDB RWY 04  (CONWAY, SC)
KHYW NDB RWY 22  (CONWAY, SC)
KHZD NDB RWY 01  (HUNTINGDON, TN)
KHZR NDB RWY 36  (NEW ROADS, LA)
KIAG NDB RWY 28R (NIAGARA FALLS, NY)
KICL NDB-A       (CLARINDA, IA)
KICT NDB RWY 01R (WICHITA, KS)
KIDA NDB RWY 20  (IDAHO FALLS, ID)
KIDP NDB RWY 35  (INDEPENDENCE, KS)
KIER NDB RWY 35  (NATCHITOCHES, LA)
KIIB NDB RWY 18  (INDEPENDENCE, IA)
KIKG NDB RWY 13  (KINGSVILLE, TX)
KILN NDB RWY 04L (WILMINGTON, OH)
KILN NDB RWY 22R (WILMINGTON, OH)
KIMT NDB RWY 01  (IRON MT-KINGSFORD, MI)
KINL NDB RWY 31  (INTERNATIONAL FALLS, MN)
KIOB NDB RWY 03  (MT STERLING, KY)
KIOB NDB RWY 21  (MT STERLING, KY)
KIPJ NDB RWY 23  (LINCOLNTON, NC)
KIRS NDB RWY 18  (STURGIS, MI)
KIRS NDB RWY 24  (STURGIS, MI)
KISB NDB RWY 17  (SIBLEY, IA)
KISB NDB RWY 35  (SIBLEY, IA)
KISN NDB RWY 29  (WILLISTON, ND)
KISW NDB RWY 02  (WISCONSIN RAPIDS, WI)
KISW NDB RWY 30  (WISCONSIN RAPIDS, WI)
KITR NDB RWY 15  (BURLINGTON, CO)
KIZG NDB-B       (FRYEBURG, ME)
KJES NDB RWY 11  (JESUP, GA)
KJES NDB RWY 29  (JESUP, GA)
KJMR NDB RWY 35  (MORA, MN)
KJMS NDB RWY 31  (JAMESTOWN, ND)
KJNX NDB RWY 03  (SMITHFIELD, NC)
KJSV NDB-A       (SALLISAW, OK)
KJVW NDB RWY 12  (RAYMOND, MS)
KJVY NDB RWY 18  (JEFFERSONVILLE, IN)
KJXN NDB RWY 24  (JACKSON, MI)
KJYG NDB RWY 33  (ST JAMES, MN)
KJYL NDB RWY 23  (SYLVANIA, GA)
KJYR NDB RWY 17  (YORK, NE)
KJYR NDB RWY 35  (YORK, NE)
KKLS NDB-A       (KELSO, WA)
KLCG NDB RWY 18  (WAYNE, NE)
KLCG NDB RWY 23  (WAYNE, NE)
KLCG NDB RWY 36  (WAYNE, NE)
KLCI NDB RWY 08  (LACONIA, NH)
KLCK NDB RWY 05R (COLUMBUS, OH)
KLCK NDB RWY 23L (COLUMBUS, OH)
KLCQ NDB RWY 28  (LAKE CITY, FL)
KLDM NDB RWY 26  (LUDINGTON, MI)
KLEE NDB RWY 31  (LEESBURG, FL)
KLGD NDB-B       (LA GRANDE, OR)
KLHW NDB RWY 33R (FT STEWART, GA)
KLIU NDB RWY 01  (LITTLEFIELD, TX)
KLKR NDB RWY 24  (LANCASTER, SC)
KLLN NDB RWY 17  (LEVELLAND, TX)
KLLN NDB RWY 35  (LEVELLAND, TX)
KLNN NDB RWY 10  (WILLOUGHBY, OH)
KLOU NDB RWY 33  (LOUISVILLE, KY)
KLQK NDB RWY 05  (PICKENS, SC)
KLQR NDB RWY 17  (LARNED, KS)
KLRD NDB RWY 17L (LAREDO, TX)
KLRF NDB RWY 25  (JACKSONVILLE, AR)
KLSE NDB RWY 18  (LA CROSSE, WI)
KLUA NDB-A       (LURAY, VA)
KLUK NDB RWY 21L (CINCINNATI, OH)
KLUK NDB RWY 25  (CINCINNATI, OH)
KLUL NDB RWY 13  (LAUREL, MS)
KLWM NDB RWY 05  (LAWRENCE, MA)
KLXL NDB RWY 31  (LITTLE FALLS, MN)
KLXY NDB-A       (MEXIA, TX)
KLYO NDB RWY 17R (LYONS, KS)
KLZU NDB RWY 25  (LAWRENCEVILLE, GA)
KMAI NDB-C       (MARIANNA, FL)
KMAN NDB-A       (NAMPA, ID)
KMAO NDB RWY 04  (MARION, SC)
KMBT NDB RWY 18  (MURFREESBORO, TN)
KMDH NDB RWY 18L (CARBONDALE-MURPHYSBORO, IL)
KMDZ NDB RWY 34  (MEDFORD, WI)
KMEY NDB RWY 20  (MAPLETON, IA)
KMEZ NDB RWY 27  (MENA, AR)
KMFD NDB RWY 32  (MANSFIELD, OH)
KMFI NDB RWY 05  (MARSHFIELD, WI)
KMFI NDB RWY 16  (MARSHFIELD, WI)
KMGM NDB RWY 10  (MONTGOMERY, AL)
KMGR NDB-A       (MOULTRIE, GA)
KMGY NDB-A       (DAYTON, OH)
KMHL NDB RWY 36  (MARSHALL, MO)
KMIV NDB RWY 14  (MILLVILLE, NJ)
KMKC NDB RWY 19  (KANSAS CITY, MO)
KMKV NDB RWY 04  (MARKSVILLE, LA)
KMLE NDB RWY 12  (OMAHA, NE)
KMLJ NDB RWY 28  (MILLEDGEVILLE, GA)
KMMI NDB RWY 02  (ATHENS, TN)
KMMI NDB RWY 20  (ATHENS, TN)
KMNI NDB RWY 02  (MANNING, SC)
KMNM NDB RWY 03  (MENOMINEE, MI)
KMNZ NDB RWY 36  (HAMILTON, TX)
KMOB NDB RWY 14  (MOBILE, AL)
KMOR NDB RWY 05  (MORRISTOWN, TN)
KMPZ NDB RWY 33  (MT PLEASANT, IA)
KMQI NDB RWY 05  (MANTEO, NC)
KMQI NDB RWY 17  (MANTEO, NC)
KMQW NDB RWY 21  (MC RAE, GA)
KMQY NDB RWY 32  (SMYRNA, TN)
KMRH NDB RWY 14  (BEAUFORT, NC)
KMRH NDB RWY 21  (BEAUFORT, NC)
KMRJ NDB RWY 22  (MINERAL POINT, WI)
KMSV NDB RWY 15  (MONTICELLO, NY)
KMTH NDB-A       (MARATHON, FL)
KMTO NDB RWY 29  (MATTOON-CHARLESTON, IL)
KMUI NDB-A       (FT INDIANTOWN GAP, PA)
KMWA NDB RWY 20  (MARION, IL)
KMWH NDB RWY 32R (MOSES LAKE, WA)
KMWO NDB RWY 23  (MIDDLETOWN, OH)
KMWO NDB-A       (MIDDLETOWN, OH)
KMZH NDB RWY 04  (MOOSE LAKE, MN)
KNEL NDB RWY 24  (LAKEHURST, NJ)
KNRN NDB RWY 16  (NORTON, KS)
KNRN NDB RWY 34  (NORTON, KS)
KOAJ NDB RWY 05  (JACKSONVILLE, NC)
KOCH NDB RWY 18  (NACOGDOCHES, TX)
KODO NDB RWY 20  (ODESSA, TX)
KODX NDB RWY 13  (ORD, NE)
KOEL NDB RWY 34  (OAKLEY, KS)
KOIN NDB RWY 35  (OBERLIN, KS)
KOJC NDB-B       (OLATHE, KS)
KOKS NDB RWY 12  (OSHKOSH, NE)
KOKZ NDB RWY 13  (SANDERSVILLE, GA)
KOLD NDB RWY 22  (OLD TOWN, ME)
KOLF NDB RWY 29  (WOLF POINT, MT)
KOLS NDB-C       (NOGALES, AZ)
KOLY NDB RWY 03  (OLNEY-NOBLE, IL)
KONA NDB RWY 30  (WINONA, MN)
KONO NDB RWY 32  (ONTARIO, OR)
KONZ NDB RWY 04  (DETROIT/GROSSE ILE, MI)
KOOA NDB RWY 22  (OSKALOOSA, IA)
KOPL NDB RWY 18  (OPELOUSAS, LA)
KOPN NDB RWY 30  (THOMASTON, GA)
KORB NDB RWY 13  (ORR, MN)
KORC NDB RWY 34  (ORANGE CITY, IA)
KORE NDB RWY 01  (ORANGE, MA)
KORE NDB RWY 32  (ORANGE, MA)
KOSH NDB RWY 36  (OSHKOSH, WI)
KOSU NDB RWY 09R (COLUMBUS, OH)
KOTG NDB RWY 29  (WORTHINGTON, MN)
KOTH NDB RWY 04  (NORTH BEND, OR)
KOUN NDB RWY 03  (NORMAN, OK)
KOUN NDB RWY 35  (NORMAN, OK)
KOWP NDB RWY 35  (SAND SPRINGS, OK)
KOXD NDB RWY 05  (OXFORD, OH)
KPCW NDB RWY 27  (PORT CLINTON, OH)
KPCZ NDB RWY 31  (WAUPACA, WI)
KPEA NDB RWY 34  (PELLA, IA)
KPEO NDB RWY 28  (PENN YAN, NY)
KPHF NDB RWY 02  (NEWPORT NEWS, VA)
KPHF NDB RWY 20  (NEWPORT NEWS, VA)
KPHG NDB-A       (PHILLIPSBURG, KS)
KPHH NDB RWY 36  (ANDREWS, SC)
KPHN NDB RWY 04  (PORT HURON, MI)
KPHT NDB RWY 02  (PARIS, TN)
KPIA NDB RWY 31  (PEORIA, IL)
KPIM NDB RWY 09  (PINE MOUNTAIN, GA)
KPKF NDB RWY 36  (PARK FALLS, WI)
KPMV NDB RWY 16  (PLATTSMOUTH, NE)
KPMV NDB RWY 34  (PLATTSMOUTH, NE)
KPNA NDB-A       (PINEDALE, WY)
KPNM NDB RWY 15  (PRINCETON, MN)
KPNS NDB RWY 35  (PENSACOLA, FL)
KPOB NDB RWY 23  (FAYETTEVILLE, NC)
KPOE NDB RWY 16  (FT POLK, LA)
KPOE NDB RWY 34  (FT POLK, LA)
KPOH NDB RWY 12  (POCAHONTAS, IA)
KPOY NDB RWY 31  (POWELL, WY)
KPPA NDB RWY 17  (PAMPA, TX)
KPSN NDB RWY 36  (PALESTINE, TX)
KPTD NDB RWY 24  (POTSDAM, NY)
KPTN NDB RWY 06  (PATTERSON, LA)
KPTT NDB RWY 17  (PRATT, KS)
KPVC NDB RWY 25  (PROVINCETOWN, MA)
KPVJ NDB RWY 35  (PAULS VALLEY, OK)
KPWC NDB RWY 34  (PINE RIVER, MN)
KPWT NDB RWY 02  (BREMERTON, WA)
KPYG NDB RWY 23  (PAGELAND, SC)
KPYX NDB-A       (PERRYTON, TX)
KRBE NDB RWY 31  (BASSETT, NE)
KRCX NDB RWY 32  (LADYSMITH, WI)
KRFD NDB RWY 01  (CHICAGO/ROCKFORD, IL)
KRFI NDB-B       (HENDERSON, TX)
KRKD NDB RWY 03  (ROCKLAND, ME)
KRKD NDB RWY 31  (ROCKLAND, ME)
KRNT NDB RWY 16  (RENTON, WA)
KROG NDB RWY 20  (ROGERS, AR)
KROS NDB RWY 34  (RUSH CITY, MN)
KRRT NDB RWY 31  (WARROAD, MN)
KRSN NDB RWY 18  (RUSTON, LA)
KRSN NDB RWY 36  (RUSTON, LA)
KRSV NDB RWY 17  (ROBINSON, IL)
KRUE NDB-A       (RUSSELLVILLE, AR)
KRUQ NDB RWY 20  (SALISBURY, NC)
KRVJ NDB RWY 11  (REIDSVILLE, GA)
KRVN NDB RWY 07  (ROGERSVILLE, TN)
KRYM NDB RWY 31  (CAMP RIPLEY, MN)
KRYV NDB RWY 05  (WATERTOWN, WI)
KRYV NDB RWY 23  (WATERTOWN, WI)
KSAA NDB-A       (SARATOGA, WY)
KSAW NDB RWY 01  (MARQUETTE, MI)
KSAZ NDB RWY 14  (STAPLES, MN)
KSBD NDB RWY 06  (SAN BERNARDINO, CA)
KSBO NDB RWY 14  (SWAINSBORO, GA)
KSBU NDB RWY 34  (BLUE EARTH, MN)
KSBX NDB RWY 23  (SHELBY, MT)
KSCH NDB RWY 22  (SCHENECTADY, NY)
KSDA NDB RWY 04  (SHENANDOAH, IA)
KSDY NDB RWY 01  (SIDNEY, MT)
KSDY NDB RWY 19  (SIDNEY, MT)
KSEM NDB RWY 33  (SELMA, AL)
KSER NDB RWY 05  (SEYMOUR, IN)
KSFB NDB-B       (ORLANDO, FL)
KSFB NDB-C       (ORLANDO, FL)
KSGH NDB RWY 24  (SPRINGFIELD, OH)
KSGS NDB-B       (SOUTH ST PAUL, MN)
KSGT NDB RWY 18  (STUTTGART, AR)
KSHD NDB RWY 05  (STAUNTON/WAYNESBORO/HARR, VA)
KSHL NDB RWY 33  (SHELDON, IA)
KSHN NDB-A       (SHELTON, WA)
KSIF NDB RWY 31  (REIDSVILLE, NC)
KSIV NDB RWY 36  (SULLIVAN, IN)
KSIY NDB-A       (MONTAGUE, CA)
KSJT NDB RWY 03  (SAN ANGELO, TX)
KSJX NDB RWY 27  (BEAVER I, MI)
KSKI NDB RWY 36  (SAC CITY, IA)
KSLB NDB RWY 17  (STORM LAKE, IA)
KSLB NDB RWY 35  (STORM LAKE, IA)
KSLI NDB RWY 22L (LOS ALAMITOS, CA)
KSLN NDB RWY 35  (SALINA, KS)
KSLO NDB RWY 18  (SALEM, IL)
KSMS NDB RWY 23  (SUMTER, SC)
KSNK NDB RWY 35  (SNYDER, TX)
KSOA NDB RWY 18  (SONORA, TX)
KSOW NDB-A       (SHOW LOW, AZ)
KSOY NDB RWY 18  (SIOUX CENTER, IA)
KSPF NDB-A       (SPEARFISH, SD)
KSPS NDB RWY 33L (WICHITA FALLS, TX)
KSPW NDB RWY 30  (SPENCER, IA)
KSQI NDB RWY 07  (STERLING/ROCKFALLS, IL)
KSRB NDB RWY 04  (SPARTA, TN)
KSRE NDB RWY 16  (SEMINOLE, OK)
KSTK NDB RWY 33  (STERLING, CO)
KSTP NDB RWY 31  (ST PAUL, MN)
KSUN NDB RWY DMA (HAILEY, ID)
KSUS NDB RWY 08R (ST LOUIS, MO)
KSUS NDB RWY 26L (ST LOUIS, MO)
KSUX NDB RWY 13  (SIOUX CITY, IA)
KSUX NDB RWY 17  (SIOUX CITY, IA)
KSUX NDB RWY 31  (SIOUX CITY, IA)
KSUX NDB RWY 35  (SIOUX CITY, IA)
KSVN NDB RWY 28  (SAVANNAH, GA)
KSWO NDB RWY 17  (STILLWATER, OK)
KSWT NDB RWY 16  (SEWARD, NE)
KSWT NDB RWY 34  (SEWARD, NE)
KSWW NDB RWY 17  (SWEETWATER, TX)
KSYF NDB RWY 32  (ST FRANCIS, KS)
KTAD NDB-A       (TRINIDAD, CO)
KTAN NDB RWY 30  (TAUNTON, MA)
KTBN NDB RWY 32  (FT LEONARD WOOD, MO)
KTDW NDB-A       (AMARILLO, TX)
KTHA NDB RWY 18  (TULLAHOMA, TN)
KTIW NDB RWY 35  (TACOMA, WA)
KTNT NDB RWY 09  (MIAMI, FL)
KTOI NDB RWY 07  (TROY, AL)
KTOR NDB RWY 10  (TORRINGTON, WY)
KTOR NDB RWY 28  (TORRINGTON, WY)
KTPF NDB RWY 04  (TAMPA, FL)
KTQH NDB RWY 17  (TAHLEQUAH, OK)
KTQK NDB RWY 35  (SCOTT CITY, KS)
KTRL NDB RWY 17  (TERRELL, TX)
KTRX NDB RWY 18  (TRENTON, MO)
KTRX NDB RWY 36  (TRENTON, MO)
KTTD NDB-A       (PORTLAND, OR)
KTTN NDB RWY 06  (TRENTON, NJ)
KTUP NDB RWY 36  (TUPELO, MS)
KTVC NDB RWY 28  (TRAVERSE CITY, MI)
KTVF NDB RWY 31  (THIEF RIVER FALLS, MN)
KTVI NDB RWY 22  (THOMASVILLE, GA)
KTWF NDB RWY 26  (TWIN FALLS, ID)
KTZR NDB RWY 04  (COLUMBUS, OH)
KUCP NDB RWY 23  (NEW CASTLE, PA)
KUDG NDB RWY 23  (DARLINGTON, SC)
KUIN NDB RWY 04  (QUINCY, IL)
KUKL NDB RWY 36  (BURLINGTON, KS)
KULS NDB RWY 12  (ULYSSES, KS)
KUMP NDB RWY 15  (INDIANAPOLIS, IN)
KUNI NDB RWY 25  (ATHENS/ALBANY, OH)
KUNU NDB RWY 02  (JUNEAU, WI)
KUNU NDB RWY 20  (JUNEAU, WI)
KUTS NDB RWY 18  (HUNTSVILLE, TX)
KUUV NDB RWY 24  (SULLIVAN, MO)
KUVA NDB RWY 33  (UVALDE, TX)
KUWL NDB RWY 09  (NEW CASTLE, IN)
KUWL NDB RWY 27  (NEW CASTLE, IN)
KVHN NDB RWY 21  (VAN HORN, TX)
KVIQ NDB RWY 28  (NEILLSVILLE, WI)
KVNC NDB RWY 31  (VENICE, FL)
KVNW NDB RWY 09  (VAN WERT, OH)
KVTA NDB RWY 09  (NEWARK, OH)
KVTN NDB RWY 32  (VALENTINE, NE)
KVUJ NDB RWY 22L (ALBEMARLE, NC)
KVVV NDB RWY 34  (ORTONVILLE, MN)
KWDR NDB RWY 31  (WINDER, GA)
KWJF NDB-C       (LANCASTER, CA)
KWYS NDB RWY 01  (WEST YELLOWSTONE, MT)
KXVG NDB RWY 31  (LONGVILLE, MN)
KYKM NDB RWY 27  (YAKIMA, WA)
KYKN NDB RWY 31  (YANKTON, SD)
KYNG NDB RWY 32  (YOUNGSTOWN-WARREN, OH)
KZEF NDB RWY 25  (ELKIN, NC)
KZPH NDB RWY 18  (ZEPHYRHILLS, FL)
KZPH NDB RWY 22  (ZEPHYRHILLS, FL)
KZPH NDB RWY 36  (ZEPHYRHILLS, FL)
L39  NDB RWY 36  (LEESVILLE, LA)
L67  NDB-A       (RIALTO, CA)
M02  NDB RWY 17  (DICKSON, TN)
M18  NDB RWY 16  (HOPE, AR)
MYSM NDB RWY 10  (SAN SALVADOR, , BHS)
N94  NDB-B       (CARLISLE, PA)
NY0  NDB RWY 10  (JOHNSTOWN, NY)
NY0  NDB RWY 28  (JOHNSTOWN, NY)
S01  NDB RWY 24  (CONRAD, MT)
S39  NDB RWY 10  (PRINEVILLE, OR)
T41  NDB RWY 30  (LA PORTE, TX)
T85  NDB RWY 31  (YOAKUM, TX)
TX25 NDB RWY 17  (ATHENS, TX)
U68  NDB RWY 09  (COWLEY-LOVELL-BYRON, WY)
U76  NDB RWY 28  (MOUNTAIN HOME, ID)
X50  NDB RWY 18  (NEW SMYRNA BEACH, FL)
```

Comment: Any chance you can link to the source file from the FAA?  While most people won't have an ARINC 424 viewer handy they are available if you look hard enough, and that would make the answer useful after the database you ran the query against expires :)

Comment: Wow! So am I correct thinking this is in principle an EDI like data? I'll second the question about getting to that database. But anyways, thanks a bunch! That's way more than I was hoping for :-)

Comment: @voretaq7 I was mistaken, the dataset is not in fact free of charge; but [here's the link](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/productcatalog/digitalproducts/nfd/). It's available on a yearly subscription basis. I have access to data like this through the nature of my work. As for viewers - yes, they are out there, but they're not very good, and I don't know if any would let you do a query like this. I wrote my own script to do the query.

Comment: @dvnrrs All the ARINC viewers I've seen have been terrible (actually calling them terrible is a disservice to terrible software products, they're far worse than that). If someone offers me money maybe I'll write a Ruby gem to consume ARINC 424 and emit CSV or something useful :P

Comment: The links are dead.

Comment: The data as of 2016 is now free of charge.