# What is that wire on the picture?

Tags: aircraft-design, feature-identification, radio

[image]

I thought it was HF antenna  the What is the purpose of that?
What kind of nav aid use HF frequency?

Comment: It is, in fact, an HF antenna. Newer Herks may have HF antennae that aren’t that sort of long wire, but on older C-130’s, that is where they put them, and that is, in fact, what that is. And thus, closing as a duplicate is correct.

Comment: And want it's for?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15506/62)

Comment: That won’t help

Comment: It is an antenna for a High Frequency communication radio (HF, as opposed to VHF or UHF or etc), and communication as opposed to navigation. It's not for any sort of navigation receiver, but rather for a radio somewhat similar to Ham Radio (although perhaps with higher power).

Comment: It's for Sense antenna in ADF actually