# What is this mysterious thing on the vertical stabilizer of the Boeing 707?

Tags: feature-identification, vertical-stabilizer, boeing-707

[image]

Have you ever seen this mysterious line-shaped thing on the vertical stabilizer of a Boeing 707 or 720? What purpose does this thing do?

Comment: Could you  maybe provide a picture that is a reasonable size?

Answer (score 9):

It is the [high-frequency shortwave antenna](https://swling.com/blog/2017/01/the-company-and-history-behind-the-boeing-707-hf-antenna-coupler/) of a [707-321B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_707), specifically *Clipper Yankee Ranger* N418PA. Also present on the [KC-135](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_KC-135_Stratotanker).

You can read about [the Antenna Coupler Program](http://vipclubmn.org/couplers.html) from the people involved in its development.

You might want to look at [What radio frequency bands are associated with the long wire antennas, why do some aircraft have them and others don't?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15506/what-radio-frequency-bands-are-associated-with-the-long-wire-antennas-why-do-so) for more information.

[image: Pan-Am 707] 
[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_707)

[image: 707 HF antenna] 
[source](https://swling.com/blog/2017/01/the-company-and-history-behind-the-boeing-707-hf-antenna-coupler/)

Comment: Surely `UNIVAC Coupler` isn't the mainframe?

Comment: The Univac division of Remington Rand Corp were the creators? developers? designers? of the UNIVAC computer. A few years later they developed electrical couplers for military aircraft antennae, which were later made available to civilian airlines.