# What is the string antenna on the back of this Cessna 172 for?

Tags: cessna-172, antenna

Okay, so this question was asked before. But I didn't get the answer I wanted. I read that its some sort of antenna. what is it, what does it do, and how does it work? Also, is it in anyway related to the antenna on the to of the 707s vertical stabilizer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The one on the 707 is probably the HF antenna... https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24688/what-is-this-wire-going-from-mid-fuselage-to-the-tail-on-this-737

Comment: I was almost sure the one on the Cessna was HF as well, but it may be a loop antenna, might need a better picture of it.

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15506/what-radio-frequency-bands-are-associated-with-the-long-wire-antennas-why-do-so

Comment: So I read the article. It seems to be an adf antenna. But I saw a photo of a pc12 with one. What would be the purpose of that?