# What is the function of the cable from the front of the plane to the tail

Tags: aircraft-design, airplane

In some older aircraft like the DC-2 an external cable can be seen running from the cockpit to the tip of the tail. Is this to control the rudder?

[image: Text]

Comment: See https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15506/what-radio-frequency-bands-are-associated-with-the-long-wire-antennas-why-do-so